# why i need to run clean manually before build?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, resources, gradle-task

this is my configuration

application.yml

```
spring:
    profiles.active: ${env}
```

build.gradle

```
processResources {
    expand(project.properties)
}
```

if I run this all works fine

```
gradle clean build -Penv=a
gradle clean build -Penv=b
```

but if I run this, "env" prop remain on first configuration

```
gradle build -Penv=a
gradle build -Penv=b
```

the strange is if i put `clean { println "CLEAN" }` i see that clean is called every time with all 4 commands

Comment: Doing a build per environment is something you don't want to do. You are basically deploying untested artifacts to a new environment.

Comment: @M.Deinum what you suggest for a spring boot on AWS Elastik Beanstalk ?

Comment: specify an environment variable named `SPRING_PROFILES_ENABLED`.

Comment: yes but AWS Elastik Beanstalk seams do not permit that

Comment: no, sorry my mistake. found it in Configuration - Software - Environment properties

Comment: just to know is SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE not SPRING_PROFILES_ENABLED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle uses each task's inputs and outputs to perform an up to date check. If the inputs & outputs haven't changed since the last run it can be skipped. You'll need to add the 'env' as a task input so it's considered in the up to date check.

Eg:

```
processResources {
    inputs.properties(project.properties)
    expand(project.properties)
}
```

See [up to date checks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks)

Comment: thz, there is a way to add all property at once to generalize code?

Comment: Yup `inputs.properties(project.properties)` see [TaskInputs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html)